# How change date Format column in csv.bz2 and update file in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a bz2 compressed csv file with millions of records.The first row contains the file header.
I have multiple date columns but there are only two specific columns that i need to change to
Format the date from yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mm and set it to dd/mm/yy hh24:mm and update the csv.bz2 file.
I was looking researching with awk, with this

```sh
bzcat OBACountryIPTV_CALICUX_Report_Session_Local_Timezone_2021-07-02_000000.csv.bz2 |
head -1 | sed 's /; / \ n / g' | nl
```

I managed to find the position of the columns that I need to reformat:

```
  1  playtime
  2  traffic
  .
  .
 30  end_time
 31  start_time
 .
 .
122  playback_id
```

The output of each row for example:

```
0.0;0.0;;0.0;0;;0.0;0;0.0;0.0;7.0;-1.0;0.0;0.0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.0;0.0;0.0;;;0.0;0.0;2021/05/11 17:52;2021/05/11 17:52;0.0;Argentina;;;;LATAM;Unknown;WIFI;Undefined;;Undefined;Streaming;TELEFE;N/A - Multicast;;LIVE;;STB;;;;;;;;Not reported;;;29_2255508521_1620777131852;{"channel_id": 3346, "channel_name": "TELEFE", "channel_number": null, "delaytime": null, "dist_id": null, "player_session_name": null, "playtime": null, "program_id": 500508915, "resolution": "HD", "device_version": "2020.06.26.00.08.27", "ip": "10.241.164.84", "ob": "29", "device_type": null, "user_id": "17059165", "device_id": "2255508521", "operation": "LIV/channel-change", "transaction_id": "476707713_2255508521_29", "status": null, "timestamp": "2021-05-11T20:52:11.852-03:00", "bit_rate": "7Mbps", "qoe_sessionId": null, "type_event": null};;;;;N/A;17059165;;10.241.164.84;IPv4;29;HD;;;;;;;;;WIFI;DTV;IPTV;2255508521;0;4D535443;BA-ICS42-GPON;CEICS02;SCSJS01;RCSJS01;;;;;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3.0.11;1280x720@60p;N/A;2020.06.26.00.08.27;5263162195;LiveTV;N/A;;;1;ALL;VIP4242W;239.130.1.0:22220;0;0;;;EBVS;;
```

Which in this case would be 30 and 31, but I can't find how to update that pair of fields within the file. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. A huge list of lines with a scrollbar doesn't give us anything we can easily understand and copy/paste to test with - an example using 3 or 4 lines of 4 or 5 fields each should be adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly edit a bz2 compressed file, the only way of achieving what you're asking for that I can think of is this:

```
bzcat OBACountryIPTV_CALICUX_Report_Session_Local_Timezone_2021-07-02_000000.csv.bz2 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{$30=gensub(/^..(..)\/(..)\/(..)(.*)$/, "\\3/\\2/\\1\\4","1",$30);$31=gensub(/^..(..)\/(..)\/(..)(.*)$/, "\\3/\\2/\\1\\4","1",$31);print }' | bzip2 > OBACountryIPTV_CALICUX_Report_Session_Local_Timezone_2021-07-02_000000.csv.bz2.tmp
mv OBACountryIPTV_OBACountryIPTV_CALICUX_Report_Session_Local_Timezone_2021-07-02_000000.csv.bz2.tmp CALICUX_Report_Session_Local_Timezone_2021-07-02_000000.csv.bz2  #if the size looks right and you verified the content has changed as expected.
```

I'm certain that there are easier/more efficient ways of doing the rearranging with awk; also note that `gensub` is a **GNU awk** extension and not POSIX-compliant.

Explanation of the awk part:

`BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}`  - tell awk that `;` is a field separator.

`$30=gensub(/^..(..)\/(..)\/(..)(.*)$/, "\\3/\\2/\\1\\4","1",$30)` - this parses the 30th field (the first of the unwanted date-format fields), `^..` matches the century section of the year, `(..)` captures the year and decade, the subsequent ones capture month and day, respectively. `(.*)` then captures the time.  `"\\3/\\2/\\1\\4"` reconstructs the time and date using the captured groups (they get numbered in the order they're captured, so `\\1` matches the last two digits of the year) and reassigns the value to the 30th field.

We then just repeat the same process for the 31st field.

Comment: Excellent!!!
Thank you very much Tink, it worked great. It would be too much to ask if you explain to me the regex you used and the commands?
I would like to know how it works!

Comment: Glad it worked, and not at all, I'll edit the answer to that effect.

Comment: P.S.: fue un placer ayudarte ;)

Comment: Excelente spanish Tink, agradecido total!!